# Parsing JSON from REST server

Tags: java, javascript, json, rest, jersey

What I am trying to achieve is to graph a table using Google's graph API, when the page loads, it queries my REST server for the JSON data. This is my Javascript function.

The JavaScript console doesn't show any errors.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({
                      url: 'http://localhost:8004/project5',
                      dataType: "json",
                      async:false,
                      error: function(error){
                             console.debug(error);
                         },
                      success:  function(data)
                        {
                                alert("YESSSSS");   
                                var data = data.results;    
                                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

                                    mytable[arraysize] = new terms(data[i].term1, data[i].term2, (data[i].contains)/((data[i].contains)+ (data[i].notcontains)));
                                    arraysize +=1;

                                }

                                    drawTable();

                        }


                    });
    });
```

This Is the JSON that is returned when I query the server in my browser using "http://localhost:8004/project5"

```
{
  "results":[
  {
     "term1":"test",
     "term2":"hard",
     "contains":"32",
     "notcontains":"55"
  },
  {
     "term1":"test",
     "term2":"easy",
     "contains":"32",
     "notcontains":"55"
  },
  {
     "term1":"pizza",
     "term2":"hut",
     "contains":"32",
     "notcontains":"55"
  }
   ]
}
```

The html contents of content isn't set to "YESSSS" which i was using to test to see if the function was a success. When the page loads, the rest server recognizes that it is queried and successfully returns the JSON, so I believe the problem is getting the data out of the returned JSON. Which is where I am stuck.

EDIT: it seems that my success function isn't being called. This is the function that is called in the java REST server, JAX-RS. To produce the JSON.

```
 @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String getStudentByid(@QueryParam("id") String id) {

      System.out.println("Queried");
      if (id == null)
          return Terms.stringTerms(container);
      return Terms.getTermsByFirst(container, id);
 }
```

I am getting a 
    `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8004/project5/terms.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
 error now

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: The `content` element has a class of "content" and not an ID, correct? I ask because the ID situation seems more likely.

Comment: Usually when debugging ajax stuff I add something like this line to the success function `window.ajax_result = data`. Then you can play with the result in the console.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? use Network panel to see the response. or change `success:function...` to `complete:function...`, see what happens.

Comment: In that case have you tried adding an `error` function to the AJAX request, to see if it's failing for some reason?

Comment: I just added `error` It is producing one, so the success function isn't being called.

Comment: Are you serving the HTML from the same server as the JSON? If you serve the page from http://localhost/ and the JSON from http://localhost:8004/ you will get a cross domain error. In my experience they are sometimes not reported in the console.

Comment: Nope, I am running the html locally from my C:/ drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your last edit, it seems you have a cross site scripting problem. You are making an ajax request to a site which is in a different domain to where your HTML page was served.

Maybe you only have this problem in development, and in production the HTML page will come from the same site as the ajax request. Then you should look at making your development environment similar to a real deployment.

For example, using a 'real' web server to deliver your HTML page, and not just opening the HTML page from a local drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply put 
    console.log("step1")

or 2 or 3, to various parts of your code and see where it stops logging.
Thats where your issue is.

You can also log anything else that might give you a clue.

Comment: And as suggested, liberally assign and test window.someattributes

Comment: This is not the problem, i know the success function is not working. I narrowed it down to a problem with the way the JSON is returned from the server. If I querry it with `http://localhost:8004/project5/terms.json` through my browser it works fine. However when the java script queries the server it doesn't receive any information.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Maybe it is the issue with the headers of your request.
I added another answer.